# adding a date to the items in the list and displaying them on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I am completely lost on a task where I have to add a date to the items when they are created, store them in a list and then present on my webpage.

my javascript code

```
var counter=4;
  var completelist = document.getElementById("thelist");

        var currentTime = new Date();
        todo=[todo1,todo2,todo3];

        todoButton.onclick=function addelement() {
        var userTodoInput = document.getElementById("todoInput");
            if(userTodoInput.value!=="" ){
            let node = document.createElement("LI");
                node.innerHTML = userTodoInput.value;
                completelist.appendChild(node);
                todo.push(userTodoInput);
                document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += "<div  class='todo' ><p id='t-list'> You have added this to the list of actions: " + userTodoInput.value + "</p></br></div>";
                
            } else {
                alert("Enter something in textarea")
            }
        counter++;
      
    }
```

My dom

```
<div class="todo-container" >

    <h1 class="about-heading">The todo list </h1>

    <p id="todo-paragraph">On this page you are able to add new items to your to-do list </p>


    <div class="todo-items">
<ul id="thelist">
    <li class="todo"id="todo1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="todo" id="todo2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="todo" id="todo3"> Item 3</li>
</ul>
<input id="todoInput" type="text" name="todoInput" placehoder="Type your to-do here">
<button  id="todo-button" >Add Item </button>

<div id="mydiv">

</div>
    </div>
```

what would you suggest on this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I have no idea how to proceed on this assignment

Comment: What is the trigger for your action? I guess, you should add `onclick` event on your button and invoke your function on button click.

Comment: If you are "completely lost" with access to all of the information, how do you expect us to be able to solve the issue with a single sentence explanation? Please try to put yourself in the shoes of the people reading your question, and provide all of the relevant information you can.

Comment: the basic idea is that I have items in my li list and I want to be able to create an array where i store these values and append a current date to them, and then to be able to sort by the date, however i do not know how to write this in code

Comment: A little something to get the current date is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) I think you are also asking for that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, your `todoButton` is not defined anywhere in your code.

If you add `var todoButton = document.getElementById("todo-button");`, your script should be working.

EDIT:
If you want to append date to user input, check edited code below. I stored `userTodoInput` and `currentTime` to single variable, named `newItem` and then place the variable on places you need it. I hope this help.

```js
var counter = 4;
var completelist = document.getElementById("thelist");

var currentTime = new Date();
todo = [todo1, todo2, todo3];

todoButton.onclick = function addelement() {
  var userTodoInput = document.getElementById("todoInput");
  if (userTodoInput.value !== "") {
    let node = document.createElement("LI");
    let newItem = `${userTodoInput.value} ${currentTime}`;
    node.innerHTML = newItem;
    completelist.appendChild(node);
    todo.push(newItem);
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += "<div  class='todo' ><p id='t-list'> You have added this to the list of actions: " + newItem + "</p></br></div>";

  } else {
    alert("Enter something in textarea")
  }
  counter++;
```

Comment: excuse me for a poorly asked question, i do indeed have this line of code, but the problem is that i dont know how to make this script correct

Comment: If you have this line of code, then post full code, not just parts of it, so we can easier help you with your problem. Which part of script is not working then?

Comment: in my script i just add an element but i dont add the date, how to append the date to an array of li items?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the following commented code. Obviously it is a basic implementation, but I think that main concepts are clear:

```js
// GET ELEMENTS.
const list = document.getElementById('list');
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const button = document.getElementById('button');

const onClickHandler = () => {
  // CHECK FOR TO-DO NAME.
  if (input.value) {
    // USE ELEMENT CHILDREN COUNT AS INDEX.
    const index = list.children.length;
    // CREATE li ELEMENT PROGRAMMATICALLY.
    const li = document.createElement('LI');
    // INSTANTIATE A NEW DATE OBJECT.
    const date = new Date();
    
    // ADD ATTRIBUTES.
    li.id = `todo${index}`;
    li.class = 'todo';
    li.innerText = `${input.value} - ${date.toString()}`;
    
    // ADD ELEMENT TO DOM.
    list.appendChild(li);
  } else {
    alert('Please type your to-do.')
  }
};

// ADD EVENT LISTENER.
button.addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>The todo list</h1>

    <p>On this page you are able to add new items to your to-do list</p>

    <div>
      <ul id="list"></ul>
    </div>

<input id="input" type="text" name="todo" placeholder="Type your to-do here">

<button id="button" type="button">Add Item</button>
</div>
```